# Regular expression between undersore and dot

Tags: regex

I want to extra alphanumeric between the third underscore and dot, example below

```
CSV_20121023000854Z_MMSC_35dbc3f813.csv
```

expected output:

```
35dbc3f813
```

This regix would solved the problem `(\_\w{15}\_\w{4}\_)(\w+)` , however i wan it to be more flexi in case the string size is increase. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
_([^_]+)\.csv
```

It'll capture everything between the last underscore and `.csv`.

Alternatively, you can split it with your language of choice:

```
>>> s = 'CSV_20121023000854Z_MMSC_35dbc3f813.csv'
>>> s.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
'35dbc3f813'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_(\w+)\.csv
```

regex work on greedy pattern and it will keep on matching the pattern and will extract the last pattern that is matched which is in  your case the required String.

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't work with JavaScript's and Python's regex engines. Neither does `_(.*?)\.csv`

Comment: I think user1902849 needs to be more descriptive in his question so that the exact environment is known. BTW.. your second solution is good as well :)

Comment: How do you test your regex?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex that doesn't care about lengths of strings between the underscores:

```
^.*?_.*?_.*?_(\w+)\..*$
```

The matching portion can even have an underscore in it (matching after the third underscore).  Dot's can appear before the third underscore.

Here is an example of it in action:
http://regex101.com/r/jT9fR0

Answer (score 0):

You have said that there are three underscore characters present in the input string,

1)If you are sure that some characters will present between _ characters, then the regex should be like:

```
.+?_.+?_.+?_(.+)\..+
```

2) If not then the regex should be like:

```
.*?_.*?_.*?_(.+)\..*
```

the question mark after the greedy operators makes the operators reluctant.